# StopIteration: iteration not started error using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor Arcpy Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, calculate-values

I got error of `StopIteration: iteration not started` and I don’t know why. I have a shapefile. First I made a layer feature by selecting `Side = R`  from ID : 0 to 99. I would like the code starts from 99 (which is the last one) and subtracts each `DiffZ` value from the next value and whenever reaches to the value higher than > abs(1) break it and update only that one row.
[image]
[image]

```
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "layer")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Side = 'R'")
    val1 = 0
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("layer", ['OID@','DiffZ','Selected']) as cursor:
        for row in sorted(cursor,reverse = True):
            val2 = row[1]
            row[2] = abs(val1 - val2)
            val1 = val2
            if val2 > 1:
                row[2] = val2
                print(row)
                #cursor.updateRow(row)
                #break
```

[image]

[66, 4, 4] is the one that I am looking for.

Comment: @BERA yes right.

Comment: An ArcPy cursor is a one-way iterable through a data set.  When you pass the cursor to `sorted`, the cursor is fully iterated so you can't do anything with it unless you reset it.  That said, even resetting the cursor won't work with your code as written.